# Reply to Incoming Message Twilio SMS Python Quickstart

Tags: python, twilio, virtualenv, bots

I'm currently working on the Twilio SMS Quickstart; specifically I'm stuck on the "Reply to an incoming message using Twilio SMS".

*update, I've realized I haven't used the 'request' module I imported from Flask. Would appreciate any tips on if I need to utilize this module and, if I do, how do I use it in this specific script?

Up to this point I've successfully sent a message using a Twilio script called "send_sms.py". I'm now stuck with being unable use my virtualenv to receive and reply to messages. Here's the code titled 'run.py':

```
from flask import Flask, request    
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/sms', methods=['POST'])    
def sms_ahoy_reply():    
    """Respond to incoming messages with a friendly SMS."""    
    # Start our response    
    resp = MessagingResponse()

    # Add a message
    resp.message("Ahoy! Thanks so much for your message.")

    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
app.run(debug=True)
```

I get an error from my code editor, Spyder, next to 'from flask import Flask, request'; however, when I delete ', request' the error goes away.

As a result of this issue I'm unable to successfully run the script which would allow me to receive and reply to text messages via Twilio.

Comment: Copy/Paste your code into the post. Don't put a picture of it...

Comment: @dfundako, thanks for pointing that out! Just fixed it.

Comment: Try separate from flask import Flask, request into two lines: from flask import Flask \n from flask import request. If it still doesn't work, see if you do have a request can be imported from flask.

Comment: Also what is the error you got? Did you define a `request` somewhere else?

Comment: Hey Haochen here's the output of the debug file:

debugfile('C:/Users/danie/Envs/sms_quickstart/run.py', wdir='C:/Users/danie/Envs/sms_quickstart')
> c:\users\danie\envs\sms_quickstart\run.py(6)<module>()
      4 
      5 @author: danie
----> 6 """
      7 
      8 # /usr/bin/env python

Comment: I don't think you need `request` in this particular code. Can you run the file without `request` being imported?